# Distance between element and cursor increases when vertically scrolling during drag in angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, css

I have implemented drag and drop functionality by using event-emitter in angular 5.  Dragging the child div element inside my parent container div. Dragging is working as fine.if vertical scroll bar occur then there is misalignment between cursor and draggable div element

`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="map">
      <img style="width:100%;height: 100%" style="cursor: pointer;" id="imgMap" 
       class="img-thumbnail" 
       src="https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/n/3cpbpra_1422080.jpg?q=80"
      alt=""/><div *ngFor="let xandYcoordinate of xandYcoordinates"><div appTagDraggable 
         [style.left.%]="xandYcoordinate.left" 
         [style.top.%]="xandYcoordinate.top" class="box" 
        (window:resize)="onResize($event)" 
         [style.width.%]="xandYcoordinate.width" 
         [style.height.%]="xandYcoordinate.height"
        (dragStart)="onDragStart()" (dragMove)="onDragMove($event)" 
       (dragEnd)="onDragEnd()">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: can you share full code? you need to adjust for offsetParent's scrollTop values.

Comment: also please make sure you specify that you only use mouse events correct? (as you use drag & drop api). You have to share at least the methods code

Comment: i will update my code in stackblitz and i share the link to u.

Comment: OK. I just had a very similar situation as I was doing drag and drop in a scrollable page so share your code - will help get it work well

Comment: ya sure .. i will update my code today in stackblitz